# Avoiding/skipping singularity error in ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I've looked up a few examples of similar errors for ODE's with singular points, but have yet to figure out a way to solve this problem for my case. A simple patch up where the singular point is 'skipped' would be sufficient for me, but I would really appreciate some help.

**Edit**: my point being that `ParametricNDSolve` is giving the `` ParametricNDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.13801826916665527`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. `` error

So I have a velocity equation *V(x,t)* for a particular as a function of *(x,t)* and some other parameters:

**Edit**: in my original unedited post, I think the code was copying across incorrectly. The following should show the issues with the `ParametricNDSolve` hitting the singularities.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

v = 0.3;
k0r = k0;
k0l = k0;
\[Sigma]r = \[Sigma];
\[Sigma]l = \[Sigma];
A[x_, t_, k0_, \[Sigma]_, \[Alpha]_] = 
  Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] \[Sigma]r Sqrt[(1 - v)/(
    1 + v)] \[Alpha] E^(-2 ((1 - v)/(1 + v)) (t - x)^2 \[Sigma]r^2) - 
   Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] \[Sigma]l Sqrt[(1 + v)/(
    1 - v)] (1 - \[Alpha]) E^(-2 ((1 + v)/(
      1 - v)) (t + x)^2 \[Sigma]l^2) + 
   Sqrt[(1 + v)/(
    1 - v)] (-Sqrt[(2/\[Pi])] Sqrt[\[Sigma]r \[Sigma]l] Sqrt[k0l/k0r]
       Sqrt[\[Alpha] (1 - \[Alpha])]
       E^(-((1 + v)/(1 - v)) (t + x)^2 \[Sigma]l^2 - ((1 - v)/(
         1 + v)) (t - x)^2 \[Sigma]r^2) (Cos[
         k0r (-Sqrt[((1 - v)/(1 + v))] (t - x)) + 
          k0l Sqrt[(1 + v)/(1 - v)] (t + x)] - 
        2*\[Sigma]l^2/k0l Sqrt[(1 + v)/(
         1 - v)] (t + x) Sin[
          k0r (-Sqrt[((1 - v)/(1 + v))] (t - x)) + 
           k0l Sqrt[(1 + v)/(1 - v)] (t + x)])) + 
   Sqrt[(1 - v)/(
    1 + v)] (Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[\[Sigma]r \[Sigma]l] Sqrt[k0r/k0l]
       Sqrt[\[Alpha] (1 - \[Alpha])]
       E^(-((1 + v)/(1 - v)) (t + x)^2 \[Sigma]l^2 - ((1 - v)/(
         1 + v)) (t - x)^2 \[Sigma]r^2) (Cos[
         k0r (-Sqrt[((1 - v)/(1 + v))] (t - x)) + 
          k0l (Sqrt[(1 + v)/(1 - v)] (t + x))] + 
        2*\[Sigma]r^2/k0r Sqrt[(1 - v)/(
         1 + v)] (t - x) Sin[
          k0r (-Sqrt[((1 - v)/(1 + v))] (t - x)) + 
           k0l Sqrt[(1 + v)/(1 - v)] (t + x)]));

B[x_, t_, k0_, \[Sigma]_, \[Alpha]_] = 
  Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] \[Sigma]r Sqrt[(1 - v)/(
    1 + v)] \[Alpha] E^(-2 ((1 - v)/(1 + v)) (t - x)^2 \[Sigma]r^2) + 
   Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] \[Sigma]l Sqrt[(1 + v)/(
    1 - v)] (1 - \[Alpha]) E^(-2 ((1 + v)/(
      1 - v)) (t + x)^2 \[Sigma]l^2) + 
   Sqrt[(1 + v)/(
    1 - v)] (Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[\[Sigma]r \[Sigma]l] Sqrt[k0l/k0r]
       Sqrt[\[Alpha] (1 - \[Alpha])]
       E^(-((1 + v)/(1 - v)) (t + x)^2 \[Sigma]l^2 - ((1 - v)/(
         1 + v)) (t - x)^2 \[Sigma]r^2) (Cos[
         k0r (-Sqrt[((1 - v)/(1 + v))] (t - x)) + 
          k0l Sqrt[(1 + v)/(1 - v)] (t + x)] - 
        2*\[Sigma]l^2/k0l Sqrt[(1 + v)/(
         1 - v)] (t + x) Sin[
          k0r (-Sqrt[((1 - v)/(1 + v))] (t - x)) + 
           k0l Sqrt[(1 + v)/(1 - v)] (t + x)])) + 
   Sqrt[(1 - v)/(
    1 + v)] (Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[\[Sigma]r \[Sigma]l] Sqrt[k0r/k0l]
       Sqrt[\[Alpha] (1 - \[Alpha])]
       E^(-((1 + v)/(1 - v)) (t + x)^2 \[Sigma]l^2 - ((1 - v)/(
         1 + v)) (t - x)^2 \[Sigma]r^2) (Cos[
         k0r (-Sqrt[((1 - v)/(1 + v))] (t - x)) + 
          k0l (Sqrt[(1 + v)/(1 - v)] (t + x))] + 
        2*\[Sigma]r^2/k0r Sqrt[(1 - v)/(
         1 + v)] (t - x) Sin[
          k0r (-Sqrt[((1 - v)/(1 + v))] (t - x)) + 
           k0l Sqrt[(1 + v)/(1 - v)] (t + x)]));
```

which I am using `ParametricNDSolve` to solve:

```
params = {x, t, k0, \[Sigma] , \[Alpha]};

V[x_, t_, 
   k0_, \[Sigma]_, \[Alpha]_] = (A[x, t, k0, \[Sigma], \[Alpha]])/(B[
     x, t, k0, \[Sigma], \[Alpha]]);

Startpoints[k0i_, \[Sigma]i_, vi_, \[Alpha]i_, fr_, to_, st_, 
  nu_] := (samps = 
   Table[B @@ (params /. {k0 -> k0i, \[Sigma] -> \[Sigma]i, 
         v -> vi, \[Alpha] -> \[Alpha]i} /. t -> -2), {x, fr, to, st}];
  tab = Table[Plus @@ #[[1 ;; n]]*st, {n, 1, Length[#]}] &[samps];
  Flatten[
     Table[FirstPosition[tab, x_ /; x > n, {Length[tab]}] - 1, {n, 0, 
       1, 1/(nu - 1)}]]*st + fr)


subs = {k0 -> 5, \[Sigma] -> 1, v -> 0, \[Alpha] -> Sqrt[1]/2};
de = {xtraj'[t] == V @@ (params /. subs /. {x -> xtraj[t]}), 
   xtraj[-2] == x0};
parasols = ParametricNDSolve[de, xtraj[t], {t, -2, 2}, x0];
startpoints = 
  Startpoints @@ ({k0, \[Sigma], v, \[Alpha], -3, 3, 0.01, 50} /. 
     subs);
trajectories = 
 Table[{xtraj[t][x0], t} /. parasols, {x0, 
   startpoints}]; ParametricPlot[trajectories, {t, -2, 2}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

There are singular points in the *V(x,t)* equation, most obviously when the denominator equals zero.

Is there a way for me to tell Mathematica to 'skip' the singular points? At the singularity itself I expect the trajectory to go horizontal (the velocity being infinite for that point) before going backwards for a while, turning around and then hitting another singular point and continuing on. If one runs the code above, you can see that it Mathematica doesn't want to plot the initial conditions for which there are singular points.

Answer (score 1):

`StreamPlot` shows the trajectories without solving the ode:

```
StreamPlot[{1, V @@ (params /. subs)}, {t, -2, 2}, {x , -3, 3},FrameLabel -> { t, x}]
```

[image]

No singular points to be recognized.

Comment: Hi Ulrich, doesn't `StreamPlot` just plot the _velocity_ field rather than the trajectory `x(t)` parametrically? Also, it's a bit hard to tell whether the field shown above has singularities, but I have included a graph showing that the denominator of _V(x,t)_ is definitely zero at points. Ideally I'd like to solve the ODE while dealing with the singular points.

Comment: @j.foobles You might plot your "trajectories" together with the stream plot, fits quite well!

Comment: @j.foobles If I plot `B[0,t,5,1,1/2]` in the range `-2<t<2` I see a function without zeros!

Comment: Hi @Ulrich Neumann, I am a bit confused - perhaps some of the code copied across incorrectly from Mathematica. Nevertheless I am convinced that the denominator function has some zeroes, so I've attached a .nb file here:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak_7kWMZ0x15hJpuG74r3VEUFQIkTQ?e=dbay6L

Comment: @j.foobles You evaluate the same streamplot as in my answer?

Comment: here is the same file with the streamplot - looks similar, but slightly different:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak_7kWMZ0x15hJpvJB37Nljs_saQPw?e=eqRpWi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123739/discussion-between-j-foobles-and-ulrich-neumann).